# Upload 10000 xlxs records to mysql using django

Tags: python, mysql, django, excel, django-queryset

I have around 10k xlxs files (each with 4 different sheets and same data format for all sheets). I wanted to fetch that data and add that data to MySQL tables. With my current code it is takin around 1-2 hrs. to fetch and fill data. I wanted to optimize this and reduce time to around 5-10 mins for 10k files. Pls suggest me right solution. TIA.

```
class ImportFileView(APIView):
    def post(self,request):

        xlsx_file = request.FILES.getlist('file')  # Around 10k files

        for file in xlsx_file:

            wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

            working_sheet = wb_obj['Sheet1']
            
            create_table_one = TableOne.objects.create(
                id = working_sheet['B1'].value,
                first_name = working_sheet['B2'].value,
                last_name = working_sheet['B3'].value,
                country = working_sheet['B4'].value,
                region = working_sheet['B5'].value,
                lab = working_sheet['B6'].value,
                sample_date = working_sheet['B7'].value,
                issue_date = working_sheet['B8'].value,
                release_year = working_sheet['B9'].value,
                comments = working_sheet['B10'].value,
            )

            create_table_one.save()

            
            for col in range(2,4):
                group = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(11)].value
                name = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(12)].value
                unit = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(13)].value
                sample_unit = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(14)].value
                parameter = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(15)].value
                type = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(16)].value
                default_value = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(17)].value

                for row in range(19,90):
                    create_data = TableData.objects.create(
                        id = create_table_one.id,
                        temperature = working_sheet['A'+str(row)].value,
                        group = group,
                        name = name,
                        unit = unit,
                        sample_unit = sample_unit,
                        parameter = parameter,
                        type = type,
                        default_value = default_value,
                        actual_value = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(row)].value
                    )

                    create_data.save()

            working_sheet = wb_obj['Sheet2']
            
            for col in range(2,100):
                if working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(5)].value == None or working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(5)].value == "":
                    break
                
                group = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(5)].value
                name = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(6)].value
                unit = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(7)].value
                sample_unit = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(8)].value
                parameter = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(9)].value
                type = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(10)].value
                default_value = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(11)].value

                for row in range(13,83):
                    actual_value = working_sheet[get_column_letter(col)+str(row)].value
                    
                    create_property_table = TableProperties.objects.create(
                        id = create_assay.id,
                        temperature = working_sheet['A'+str(row)].value,
                        group = property_group,
                        name = property_name,
                        unit = unit,
                        sample_unit= sample_unit,
                        parameter = parameter,
                        type = type,
                        default_value = default_value,
                        actual_value = actual_value
                    )

                    create_property_table.save()


            working_sheet = wb_obj['Sheet3']

            for row in range(3,83):
                create_crude_data = TableCrudeData.objects.create(
                    id = create_table_one.id,
                    component = working_sheet['A'+str(row)].value,
                    pcnt = working_sheet['B'+str(row)].value
                )

                create_crude_data.save()
            

            working_sheet = wb_obj['Sheet4']

            for row in range(2,67):
                create_properties = TablePropertiesTwo.objects.create(
                    id = create_table_one.id,
                    group = working_sheet[get_column_letter(1)+str(row)].value,
                    name = working_sheet[get_column_letter(2)+str(row)].value,
                    unit = working_sheet[get_column_letter(3)+str(row)].value,
                    sample_unit = working_sheet[get_column_letter(4)+str(row)].value,
                    parameter = working_sheet[get_column_letter(5)+str(row)].value,
                    type = working_sheet[get_column_letter(6)+str(row)].value,
                    default_value = working_sheet[get_column_letter(7)+str(row)].value,
                    actual_value = working_sheet[get_column_letter(8)+str(row)].value
                )

                create_properties.save()


        return Response({
            'success' : True
        })
```

Comment: So just to be sure: You're sending out a single 1-2 hours post call to Django where it's somehow not timeouting and uploads/processes 10K documents?  What happens if the second to last one breaks? It sounds like a bad design and I would look for asynchronous ways of doing this. Potentially splitting the load and running things parallel (assuming backend can handle that).

Comment: Don't you want a small number of tables instead of 10K tables?

Comment: Are the `INSERTs` "batched" in some way?  (I don't see those detail in the code.)